# Prove that the volume of any right circular cone inscribed in a sphere is less than 30% of the volume of the sphere.

Tags: calculus, volume

Here is my proof, but I have received a lot of criticism for it from an engineer. I´ll show my proof first then the criticism. Please advise on where I went wrong (if at all)!

Let the apex of the cone be at the point $(-1,0,0)$ and the base lie in the plane $z = c$. Then the area of the base is $\pi(1-c^2)$ and the height of the cone is $c + 1$, so the volume of the cone is
$$\frac{\pi(1-c)(1+c)^2}3$$If we take the derivative of this and set the result to 0, we arrive at the equation
$$2(1-c)(1+c) - (1+c)^2 = 0 \implies 2(1-c) - (1+c) = 0 \implies c= \frac13$$The volume of the cone when $c = \frac13$ is
$$\pi \cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac43 \cdot \frac43 = \frac{\frac{32}{27}\pi}3$$Dividing this by $\frac43 \pi$ (the volume of the sphere) gives
$$\frac{32/27}{4} = \frac8{27} \approx 0.296 < 0.3$$

---

The Engineer says that $\frac43 \pi$ is not the volume of the sphere, since that volume would be correct if the sphere had a radius of 1 and he says it is very unclear that my sphere has a radius of 1.
ud.

He also says that the height of the cone cannot be c + 1.

I don´t see anything wrong with my solution.

Comment: A diagram would help. You would need to show that your constructed cone is indeed inscribed inside a particular sphere. Then work out the dimension of the sphere.

Comment: It wouldn’t have hurt to have said at the beginning that you were taking the unit sphere centred at the origin, but that really is clear from your argument and calculations, which are fine apart from a missing factor of $\frac13$ on the lefthand side of the final calculation of the volume of the cone. He’s wrong. I disagree with **Paichu**: no diagram is needed, though of course one wouldn’t hurt.

Comment: Yes, I am only referring to right cones, Ninad.

Comment: Brian: Thank you. I was just really puzzled at his reaction...almost angered. Your response is quite helpful.

Comment: I'd add one more thing: as Brian said, the argument is good, but if you want to be even clearer, you might add that we can assume $c > 0$, since any cone whose base lies in the plane $z=c < 0$ will have less volume than the cone whose base lies in $z=-c$. Then there is no question that the height is $c+1$.

Comment: @PureMathematician: You’re welcome. I’m really quite puzzled by the engineer’s objections. At best they’re awfully pedantic — and I say that as someone who tends to be a bit pedantic!

Comment: Ha! Well yes, he was very irate that in my post I had criticized a very very long solution written by an Engineer. So then I gave my solution, which is only a few lines long, and he said that I was "attacking" Engineers. He said I could not possibly be a "real Mathematician".

Comment: Theophile: Good point. I will add that. I would show you guys the whole thread, but I had the post written in the Spanish language and since I do not speak Spanish, I had to have someone translate my solution, but I do not think his problem was a language issue since I had my work translated by a native speaker. His problem was mainly about how the radius is not 1 and that the height cannot be c + 1 or something to that effect.